# Linking two models automatically in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I would like when i create new order to be linked to this company. now, i have to choose it manually

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=250)

class Order(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_date = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    order_notes = models.TextField(max_length=250)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all if every Order is connected to this particular Company creating Foreign Key is overintended. If you still want to do this for some reason here is the solution.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_date = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    order_notes = models.TextField(max_length=250)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # u have to have a new order in db
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        # then assing this particular company
        self.company = Company.objects.get(name='the_company_name', address='the_company_address')
        # and again save the changes
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

but if you want to do this this way consider making the Company `name` and `address` `unique_together`

Comment: how it s overintended ? i m building an invoicing app and want to link orders to the company, so any company i create i want to link its orders

Comment: well then the question was not clearly stated `this company` did not tell me anything about other companies. In such case the solution is quite different

Comment: I will post an answer related to your question later

Comment: Can you create another question where you exactly specify your needs so others can later on use this as a learning source? Try to describe your question/problem as simple as possible but at the same time be precise - I will post a full answer in your new question